# Windows 8 memory usage

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-8

If Windows 8 requires [same amount of RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8#Hardware_requirements) that Windows 7, why virtual box suggest 1GB of RAM for Windows 8 x86 and 512Mb of RAM for Windows 7 x86?

Comment: Why does anyone do anything?  Only they (in this case VirtualBox's creators) know "Why". Plus it's just a "suggestion", set it as you see fit. :)

Comment: Oracle and Microsoft do not talk to each other. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran Windows 7 on 512 MB RAM before. Never EVER attempt it, even the most patient person will give up using it.

VirtualBox probably realized that but it's too late to change it from Windows 7.

Comment: ^ This. Microsoft said multiple times, Windows 8 uses less memory. Again: 512 mb is not enough. Not even for 7, Vista. Even XP would struggle.

Comment: @Shiki Don't trust Microsoft is any case. However 256MB makes a smooth XP experience, from my experience.

Comment: Made, in the old times. But as software grew larger (userland, like Firefox), the more memory you need. If you would set up an XP nowadays, you would run out of that 512MB in no time.